# Excel 2007 - selecting multiple non-contiguous cells within one column

Tags: excel, multi-select

I've noticed that when one performs the above action and then copies the result back into an Excel sheet you get only those cells selected - which is great. However when one copies the selected cells into notepad, you get the complete range.

Is there a way around this..?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on http://superuser.com?

Comment: @quip: Yes, it should be on superuser.com, and I'm voting to migrate it. However, belongs-on-* tags are generally frowned upon, and Jeff Atwood himself has come down against using those tags. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22087/belongs-on-tags/22099#22099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - copy once - to excel and then - the copied column to notepad....

Comment: sure, and this extra step isn't the end of the world - but can it be avoided somehow..?